# Amazon Redshift dateadd() in CASE statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to add the date in a case statement

```
select the_date, 
(case 
when the_date like '%years%' then dateadd(year,REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(condition_, '-?[0-9]+\.? years'),'years',''),the_date)
end) 
from customer
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> SQL Error [500310] [42883]: Amazon Invalid operation:
>   function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", text, timestamp with time
>   zone) does not exist;

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the second parameter to `INT` and the third parameter to `timestamp` (currently it's `timestamptz`.

This is the [`DATEADD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) signature:

```
DATEADD( datepart, interval, {date|timestamp} )
```

Your query should look something like:

```
select the_date, 
(case when the_date like '%years%' then 
    dateadd(
         year,
         REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(condition_, '-?[0-9]+\.? years'),'years','')::INT,
         the_date::timestamp
    )
end) 
from customer
```

---

Alternatively you could use simple `+` operator with an `interval`. This way you can preserve the `timestamptz` data type for `the_date`:

```
select the_date, 
(case when the_date like '%years%' then 
    the_date + (interval '1 year' * REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(condition_, '-?[0-9]+\.? years'),'years','')::INT)
    )
end) 
from customer
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately still the same error occurs,
SQL Error [500310] [42883]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist;

Comment: you also have to convert `the_date` from `timestamptz` to `timestamp`

Comment: Alternatively you could use simple `+` with an interval since it is supported by `timestamptz` datatype. I will add an example.